# Pathfinding algorithm with only partial knowledge of graph

Tags: partial, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I need to program an algorithm to navigate a robot through a "maze" (a rectangular grid with a starting point, a goal, empty spaces and uncrossable spaces or "walls"). It can move in any cardinal direction (N, NW, W, SW, S, SE, E, NE) with constant cost per move.

The problem is that the robot doesn't "know" the layout of the map. It can only view it's 8 surrounding spaces and store them (it memorizes the surrounding tiles of every space it visits). The only other input is the cardinal direction in which the goal is on every move.

Is there any researched algorithm that I could implement to solve this problem? The typical ones like Dijkstra's or A* aren't trivialy adapted to the task, as I can't go back to revisit previous nodes in the graph without cost (retracing the steps of the robot to go to a better path would cost the moves again), and can't think of a way to make a reasonable heuristic for A*.

I probably could come up with something reasonable, but I just wanted to know if this was an already solved problem, and I need not reinvent the wheel :P

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't solved, but like with many planning problems, there is a large amount of research already available.

Most of the work in this area is based on the original work of R. E. Korf in the paper "Real-time heuristic search". That paper seems to be paywalled, but the [preliminary results](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1987/AAAI87-024.pdf) from the paper, along with a discussion of the Real-Time A* algorithm are still available.

The best recent publications on discrete planning with hidden state (path-finding with partial knowledge of the graph) are by [Sven Koenig](http://idm-lab.org/publications.html). This includes the significant work on the Learning Real-Time A* algorithm.

Koenig's work also includes some demonstrations of a range of algorithms on theoretical experiments that are far more challenging that anything that would be likely to occur in a simulation. See in particular ["Easy and Hard Testbeds for Real-Time Search Algorithms"](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/Koen96d.html) by Koenig and Simmons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I skimmed the papers, and I'm certain that they would have led me to implement a much better solution than the one I came up with in the end. Wish I had gotten your answer a month ago :P